# Jenkins pipeline :code for Jenkins ci cd pipeline to run with two suites at time means single job

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Help me
jenkins
********Jenkins cicd pipeline: how to run selenium /cypress integration folder**** /two suites run at time (single jenkins job)**

details we have a cypress integration folder in these two suites regression suite and smoke suite.

1.chrome heedless- browser

2.env is int,prd,prd01

3.we need to run both suites run at a time (single Jenkins job).

requested to best coding.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is a conflict when the two test tools run at a time. For example, both of your command or scripts will create a folder with same name, so the second command will fail in this case.

If no, then you may can refer to **parallel jobs** in Jenkins.

Code example as below, i believe you can search a lot good example with the keyword

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage(“Compile & Build Binary”) {
            parallel {
                stage(“Build X”) {
                     sh(‘cd /path/to/proj-1 && make && make publish’)
                }
                stage(“Build Y”) {
                      sh(‘cd /path/to/proj-2 && make && make publish’)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```